# SVN working copy won't commit to my repository

Tags: svn

I'm having problems with Subversion. I have set up repository "ukcpi_alpha" and a site "CPI":

```
svn+ssh://example.com@example.com/home/129224/data/svn/ukcpi_alpha/CPI
```

I can connect and get a working copy fine however I can't commit all the files back once changes have been made I get this error:

```
No repository found in 'svn+ssh://example.com@example.com/home/129224/data/svn'
```

To be specific I can actually commit individual files from the root but when I select the working copy folder it doesn't want to commit and folders within the working copy don't commit either.

Any ideas on what is going on and how to fix? (I'm using the mac app versions by the way)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the directory permissions for your repository?